# Configurar o index da imagem que receberá o style

Tags: jquery, css3

Tenho um grupo de `imagens` dentro de uma `div`:

```
<div class="boxSlide">
   <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" />
   <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" />
   <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" />
</div>
```

Gostaria de saber o `index` de cada uma para usar na `função` abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide").click(function() {
      index = $(this).index();
      $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide img").css("opacity",0);
      $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide img").prop("index",index).css("opacity",1);
  });

});
```

Mas não dá certo. Já tentei como abaixo também mas o resultado é o mesmo.

```
$("div.slideShow div.boxSlide img").val(index).css("opacity",1);
```

Parece que essa parte não indica qual a `figura` que deve receber o `style`

```
.prop("index",index)
```

Eis o HTML

```
<div class="slideShow">
  <div class="boxSlide">
     <img class="aberturaSelect" src="_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" />
     <img class="aberturaSelect" src="_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" />
     <img class="aberturaSelect" src="_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" />
     <div class="anterior">
        <span class="setaSpan"><</span>
        <span class="boxSpan"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="proximo">
        <span class="setaSpan">></span>
        <span class="boxSpan"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contador">
     <span class="contaSlide">1</span>
     <span class="contaSlide">2</span>
     <span class="contaSlide">3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consegui:

```
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide img").eq(index).css("opacity",1);
```

Obrigado!